# Estimate Convolution Filter Formula from Noisy Input and Output

Tags: convolution, signal-processing

When I learned signal processing, I learned how to calculate the output with given input and given convolution filter. However, if now I have the noisy input and output, assuming the system is linear time invariant hence the input and output is connected by a convolutional filter, how should I calculate the exact formula of filter from data?

This sounds more like a machine learning problem instead of a signal processing problem. I do not even know how to start with this problem, like what is the criterion (e.g. maximum likelihood) for evaluating how good a candidate filter is. Is there such a field that studies this kind of problems?

EDIT: Right now I consider only the simplest case. The input and output are both 1D signal that varies in time, and the noise is assumed to be Gaussian noise with zero mean and unknown variance. The prior knowledge of the filter is it should be monotonically decreasing with time lag, possibly exponentially decay.

Comment: 1) What is the signal (e.g. time series or image)? Do you have a single observed signal or multiple signals? 2) What is the nature of the input and output noise (e.g. i.i.d. additive Gaussian noise, or something more complicated)? Do you know (or have the ability to measure) parameters of the noise distribution? 3) Do you have any prior information about the structure of the signal or the filter?

Comment: @user20160 Just edited the question. Right now I only focus on the simplest case to see how any algorithm would work in this problem.